# why does adding a DNS root zone to the URL sometimes result in security errors?

Tags: domain-name-system, google-chrome, security

Disclaimer: I've only witnessed this behaviour on chrome. 
adding the rightmost dot to a URL as in **[facebook.com.](http://facebook.com.)** should result in a  fully qualified domain name (FQDN) and hence I wouldn't expect any problems when resolving that url. However chrome throws a security error the first time you're trying to access it.

is there an explanation for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolving is not the problem.
Facebook uses by default HTTPS, the SSL certificate facebook uses at https://www.facebook.com/ has a CN (Common Name) of `www.facebook.com` not `www.facebook.com.`.
Your browser checks the CN of the certificate against the hostname, it doesn't match and it throws a security warning.

I don't know why it's only the first time for you, I don't use Chrome, maybe it permanently saves your choice to accept this mismatch.
Or maybe you didn't notice that once you accepted it, facebook will actually redirect `www.facebook.com.` to `www.facebook.com`.